# How to convexify a nonconvex function?

Tags: optimization, convex-analysis, convex-optimization, non-convex-optimization

Given $b > 0$, let  $f : \Bbb R_{>0}^2 \to \Bbb R$ be

$$f(x,y) := \frac{x}{y \log_2 \left(1 + b \frac{x}{y}\right)}$$

I would like to prove that $f$ is convex.

I tried to use the definition of convexity (i.e., the Hessian matrix) but it seems to be non-convex. Is there any transformation I could do to make my function convex?

Comment: Can you precise what transformation you're expecting? If I transform your function into the always vanishing map I get a convex map...

Comment: I'm not expecing something specific. I'm new to convex optimization problems. The above function is a constraint to my problem. I have proven that my objective function and the other constraints of the problem are convex, but i couldn't prove it for this constraint.

Comment: So i hoped there was something i could do to to prove the convexity of this function, in order my problem to be convex

Comment: I assume you're hoping to globally minimize $f$ using gradient descent or some other local minimization procedure? So what you're looking for is some convex function which shares a minimum with $f$?

Comment: Something like that

Comment: I've read something about convex envelopes to replace any non-convex function. So I was thinking finding one.

Answer (score 1):

$f(x,y)$ is not convex. For $b=1$ try points $A=[10,1]$ and $B=[30,1]$ and the value at the midpoint:

$f(A) = 2.8906482,~f(B) = 6.0554725,~f\left(\frac{A+B}{2}\right) = 4.5534049 > \frac{f(A)+f(B)}{2} = 4.4730604$

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I know it is not convex, i was just wondering if i could change it somehow in order to have a convex result.

Comment: Try to define, how you would like to change it. As stated above, change it to a convex function having the same global minimum? This would be I think very difficult task in general. I am not aware of any algorithm, which would try to do it in this way.